# Bijection Between Equivalence Classes and Non-Negative Reals

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

Consider the following equivalence relation:

$ (x_1, x_2)  \sim (y_1 ,y_2)$ iff $ x_1^2 + x_2^2 = y_1^2 + y_2^2 $

Now, find a bijection $ f: R^2/ \sim  \rightarrow  [0, \infty) $. From my understanding, the set of equivalence classes represents points on circles of any radius $ r \in R $. However, I am struggling with defining a bijective function, as I am failing injectivity on any attempt. Can someone provide some hint?

Comment: Hint: you can map an equivalence class to the (squared) radius of the circle it represents. Don't forget to check that the map is well-defined

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I am struggling on injectivity. Because, for such a map, if f(x) = f(y) = r, then it does not mean that x = y...

Comment: Remember that you are working with **equivalence classes**, so $[(x,y)] \mapsto x^2 + y^2$

Comment: Yes, does it not fail injectivity as there are multiple points within the class that fit the radius?

Comment: You should check your definition of your equivalence relation and then consider the function again. We want the equivalence classes of the points to be equal, not the points themselves

Comment: @user2661923 The function $f$ has domain $\mathbb R^2 / \sim$ though, and not $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: @hff1 Good catch, my mistake.  I have therefore deleted my previous comment.

Comment: The equivalence class of a point $(x,y)$ is $[(x,y)] = \{(w,z)|w^2 + z^2 = x^2+y^2\}$.  So So if we define $f([(x,y)]) = x^2 + y^2$ we are set.   If $f([x,y]) =f([x',y'])= r$ then $x^2 + y^2 = r$ and $x'^2 + y'^2 = r$.  And so $x^2 + y^2 = x'^2 + y'^2$ and so $(x,y)\sim (x',y')$ so $[(x,y)]= \{(w,z)|w^2 + z^2 = x^2 + y^2\}=\{(w,z)|w^2 + z^2=r\} = \{(w,z)|w^2 + z^2 = x'^2 + y'2\}=[(x',y')]$.  So injective (assuming we have actually proven it is an equivalence relation.).

Comment: Oh, I guess in my comment above, I must show that $f([x,y])=x^2 + y^2$ is well defined.  That is if if $[x',y'] = [x,y]$ so $f([x',y']=x'^2 + y'^2$ that will be the same result as $f([x,y])=x^2 + y^2$.  That must be shown.

Comment: @fleablood  I agree with your definition, but how do I show surjectivity now? Given any nonnegative r, how do I show exists (x,y) such that f([x,y]) = r?

Comment: If $x^2 +y^2 = r$ then $f([x,y])= r$.  Can you find a representative pair, ***ANY*** representative pair where $x^2 +y^2 =r$?  Any at all?  Hint 1:  If $x^2 +y^2 =r$ then $x=\pm\sqrt{r-y^2}$.  Hint 2:  $0$ is a number.  Hint 3: So is $\sqrt r$.  Hint 4:  $0^2 + (\sqrt r)^2 = r$.  Hint 5: $\sqrt{\frac r2}^2 + \sqrt{\frac r2}^2 = r$  Hint 6:  If $y^2 \le r$ then $\sqrt{r-y^2}^2 - y^2 = r$.